# How to pass a file from a function to another in PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5

I'm trying to pass a file name from one function to another. In particular, I'm using PyQt5, and created 3 buttons that if clicked starts the following functions:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtMultimedia


def select_function():
    file = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName()
    return file

def play_function():
    global file
    QtMultimedia.QSound.play(file)

def stop_function():
    global file
    QtMultimedia.QSound.stop(file)
```

Basically, I want the first function select_function() to choose a file, and then pass the file to the second function play_function(). I also want the third function to be activated if the button is pressed, and the file has to be one from select_function().

Is this even doable?

Comment: If you have another problem then create another post, do not modify the existing post

Answer (score 2):

If you want to pass information between functions, it is better to use a class since it allows you to have a common scope, so sharing information is simple and avoids the use of global variables.

```py
from functools import cached_property
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QFileDialog, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout, QWidget
from PyQt5.QtMultimedia import QSound


class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self._filename = ""
        self._qsound = None

        lay = QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(self.load_button)
        lay.addWidget(self.play_button)
        lay.addWidget(self.stop_button)

        self.load_button.clicked.connect(self.handle_load_clicked)
        self.play_button.clicked.connect(self.handle_play_clicked)
        self.stop_button.clicked.connect(self.handle_stop_clicked)

    @property
    def filename(self):
        return self._filename

    @cached_property
    def load_button(self):
        return QPushButton("Load")

    @cached_property
    def play_button(self):
        return QPushButton("Play")

    @cached_property
    def stop_button(self):
        return QPushButton("Stop")

    def handle_load_clicked(self):
        filename, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName()
        if filename:
            self._filename = filename

    def handle_play_clicked(self):
        self.handle_stop_clicked()
        self._qsound = QSound(self.filename)
        self._qsound.play()

    def handle_stop_clicked(self):
        if self._qsound is not None:
            self._qsound.stop()
        self._qsound = None


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```